# ImportError: No module named utils.read

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `main.py` file in the folder `project` and `read.py` in the folder `./project/utils`. In the `main.py`, I called

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('./utils/')
from utils.read import function1
```

However, when I use the `python main.py` command, I got the error 
`ImportError: No module named utils.read`. What should I change? Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you need to add `__init__.py`

in your directory..

make sure you have `__init__.py` in `utils` folder.. then only python will understand it is package folder contains py

Comment: What should I insert in the file `__init__.py`?

Comment: simply create __init_.py under utils folder.. you dont need to put anything into it.. it just to identify its package folder

Answer (score 1):

`__init__.py` specifies that the folder is actually a package. a package in python is a directory containing .py files (modules). In every folder which is a package (that is, a folder containing multiple .py files) you should define `__init__.py`. 
It can be empty, or you can put some statements to execute when the package is imported (or modules from the package).

For exmaple, let's take this directory tree:
**/dev/package/greeter.py**
and current working directory is **/dev**.

```
>>> from package import greeter

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from package import greeter
ImportError: No module named package
```

`import pakcage` results in the same error. **When adding __init__.py into the package folder**, it works. My init is simple as

`print 'init executed'`

```
>>> from package import greeter
init executed

>>>
```

One common functionality to put in `__init__.py` is the `__all__` variable. You can read more about it here [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)